# FTP server-like asp.net web site

Tags: asp.net, wcf, file, upload, ftp

This question is kinda tricky. I have a WCF web service for file upload and download process with several parameters. One of our 3th party application have to access this web service like an ftp client.

Is there any way to do that? Do I have to write an asp.net web app in port 21, which acts like an FTP server for uploading and downloading files via my WCF service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly, you need to build your own FTP server that uses your WCF service to get and serve the files, here is a link to a custom ftp server written in C# : http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_network/sockets/article.php/c7409/A-C-FTP-Server.htm

Comment: Thank you. Like you said, I can build my own FTP Server with that example.